Why request.body is undefined when using nextAuth and next-connect with Next API Router?
I'm creating a simple todo app that posts a todo in the db. For that i'm using nextjs 14, next-auth v4 and next-connect. Everything is working fine without next-connect, the body of the request is not undefined and todo data is posted on db. But with next-connect, the body of the request is undefined. the db throws this error :

Here is the content of the request, there is not a body :


I have checked the solution everywhere and couldn't find it.
Here is the code:
The function submitHandler of the AdminPage that sends the data to the api :
const AdminPage = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const sendingData = {
      name,
      number,
    };

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/admin",
      sendingData,
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    if (data.success) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  };

The api/admin/route.js code:
import { createEdgeRouter } from "next-connect";
import dbConnect from "@/app/dbConfig";
import { postTodo } from "@/app/method";
import { authorizeRoles, isAuthenticatedUser } from "@/app/middlewares";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const router = createEdgeRouter();

dbConnect();

router.use(isAuthenticatedUser, authorizeRoles("admin")).post((req, res) => {
  console.log("In post next-connect Method : ");
  console.log(req);
  postTodo(req, NextResponse);
});

export async function POST(request, ctx) {
  return router.run(request, ctx);
}

The isAuthenticatedUser and authorizeRoles methods in the middlewares.js file :
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import User from "./user";
import { authOptions } from "./api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";

const isAuthenticatedUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("In isAuthenticatedUser Method : ");
  console.log(req);
  const session = await getServerSession(
    req,
    {
      ...res,
      getHeader: (name) => res.headers?.get(name),
      setHeader: (name, value) => res.headers?.set(name, value),
    },
    authOptions
  );

  if (!session) {
    return new ErrorHandler("Login first to access this route", 401);
  }

  req.user = session.user;

  next();
};

const authorizeRoles = (...roles) => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.user.email }).select("role");

    if (!roles.includes(user.role)) {
      return new ErrorHandler(
        `Role (${user.role}) is not allowed to access this resource.`
      );
    }

    next();
  };
};

export { isAuthenticatedUser, authorizeRoles };

The postTodo Method that creates the todo in the db :
import Todo from "./todo";

export const postTodo = async (req, NextResponse) => {
  console.log("In postTodo Method : ");
  console.log(req);
  const receivedData = req.bdoy;
  const todo = await Todo.create(receivedData);
  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      success: true,
      message: "Data is received succesfully",
      data: todo,
    },
    { status: 200 }
  );
};

None of the request logged has a body
